# Getting error when deploying polygon supernet to local using geth local instance

Tags: blockchain, polygon

I am deploying polygon supernet by following the official guide: https://wiki.polygon.technology/docs/supernets/operate/supernets-local-deploy-supernet/#ii-funding-validators-on-the-rootchain on my Ubuntu 21.04 using the latest release package of polygon-edge_0.9.0_linux_amd64. When registering the validator using the following command
`./polygon-edge polybft register-validator --data-dir test-chain-4 --supernet-manager 0x75aA024A2292A3FD3C17d67b54B3d00435437246 --jsonrpc http://0.0.0.0:8545`
it given an "Error: register validator transaction failed"

I checked all the way from the start and verified the public addresses and validator nodes but nothing came up

Answer (score -1):

use this command
./polygon-edge polybft register-validator --data-dir ./test-chain-4 --supernet-manager 0x75aA024A2292A3FD3C17d67b54B3d00435437246 --jsonrpc http://0.0.0.0:8545

Comment: Isn't this exactly the same as what OP already tried?